# change bell sound in iTerm2

Tags: iterm2, bell

I found several answers on how to silence the bell in iTerm2 or add visual alerts to replace it.
I do find the audio bell useful, but I'm starting to hate the default sound.

I only want to change its sound; a duck quack would be better; how can I achieve that?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/2635

Comment: Of course the downside is that it may be harder to hear because [Duck Quacks Don't Echo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_Quacks_Don%27t_Echo)

Comment: FYI, my iTerm2 doesn't play the system bell sound (which of course it's already a duck quack), so this solution doesn't apply to me:

> It's the system bell sound, which you can change in System Prefs > Sound > Sound Effects